# Unexpected blank lines on console while creating object of class

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, console

I know, it sounds weird, but i am seeing a strange output with blank lines in python while creating object.

For Example:

test.py

```
from bar import Bar
from foo import Foo
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "test1"
    f = Foo(params)
    b = Bar(params)
    print "test2"
    print f.method_one()
    print b.method_one()
```

foo.py

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params
        self.arg1 = params.get('arg1')
        self.arg2 = params.get('arg2')
        self.arg3 = params.get('arg3')
        self.arg4 = params.get('arg4')
        self.argn = params.get('argn')

   def method_one(self):
       print "foo one"
```

bar.py

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params
        self.arg1 = params.get('arg1')
        self.arg2 = params.get('arg2')
        self.arg3 = params.get('arg3')
        self.arg4 = params.get('arg4')
        self.argn = params.get('argn')

   def method_one(self):
       print "bar one"
```

Below is the output of test.py

```
test1



test2
foo one
bar one
```

While expected Output is :

```
test1
test2
foo one
bar one
```

How do i avoid this blank lines while creating object?

Comment: MCVE needed --> http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show all of your `Foo` and `Bar` classes please.

Comment: You must have some `print` elsewhere…

Comment: I don't think you've posted your actual code. `print f.method_one` won't print `foo one`, you need to call the method with `f.method_one()`.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, i haven't . Just provided the program structure..

Comment: Your example is still of no use as we have no idea what params are